Recover a postgres-14 database after Ubuntu upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS
The Ubuntu 24 installer told me that postgres 16 would replace 14. After the upgrade they both seemed to be available
$ dpkg -l | grep postgresql
ii  postgresql                                    16+257build1.1                           all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
rc  postgresql-14                                 14.13-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                   amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-16                                 16.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.2                    amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Sourc

I tried to run a cluster upgrade with pg_upgradecluster first of all dropping the newly installed 16 (it seemed safe to drop it because it was new) but could not complete the upgrade because of missing binaries.
$ sudo pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log

And apt is not giving me an install option for postgres-14. Starting to panic slightly I checked my backups and found the latest is six months old. Should I just purge v14 and accept data loss, or try to find a way back?
UPDATE
Following guidance from RobM below, postgres-14 was re-installed and the data was successfully recovered. Happy ending!

rc  postgresql-14: You are seeing an entry in the package database, not the actual package. rc  means that the package has already been removed. It is not available.

thanks for the clue. I will look for the missing binaries offbox

Interesting... I have PostGIS installed and do-release-upgrade refuses to upgrade because it would need to remove postgresql-14-postgis-3 and related libraries. If I do remove them manually, the cluster migration fails due to missing GIS libraries. Installing them doesn't fix the problem because the PG14 cluster needs the older versions that aren't available.

Keeping in mind that it was always possible, that the cluster switch uses an official Debian package and that I didn't have any trouble upgrading PostgreSQL on Debian,I won't say what I think of their answer, but apparently Ubuntu decided they can't let you upgrade PostgreSQL (at least, if you have PostGIS).
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/2078745
They suggest you back up your database cluster, then remove PostgreSQL then upgrade and reinstall it.

Yep I think this is the answer - if you don't follow Ubuntu's suggestion (e.g. miss the notification as I did) there is no way back. The data is gone.

@snowboy hmmm, since I was doing upgrade testing on a clone of a VM, I did try a lot of things and in no case I ever got my old PostgreSQL 14 data deleted... it either succeed in converting the old db cluster to 16, or it fails and the data are left there. You can check what you have in /var/lib/postgresql/: if you see a directory called 14 then it contains your data. If you install again Postgres 14 from their repository, it should be able to pick it up and use it.

Check this page about how to add the official PostgreSQL repo that should let you reinstall pg14: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Thanks @RobM there is a 14 directory :-). Struggling a bit with the reinstall but will keep retrying and post back here later.
